# Why does Hyper-V-VmSwitch produce an error log of Event ID 15?

Tags: hyper-v

everyone!

I got a problem with using hyper-v.

When I use the switch what I create on hyper-v and reboot my PC, I get an error log from Hyper-V-VmSwitch.

But when I use the default switch, I don't get any error log from Hyper-V-VmSwitc.

Could anybody shed some light on it for me? 
I'd like to know why the switch I created has the error log and how to fix it.

Thank you!

The following is the error log detail:

```html
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
<System>
  <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Hyper-V-VmSwitch" Guid="{ID}" /> 
  <EventID>15</EventID> 
  <Version>0</Version> 
  <Level>2</Level> 
  <Task>1010</Task> 
  <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x8000000000000080</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2018-12-21T11:55:29.126445000Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>2618</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="4" ThreadID="472" /> 
  <Channel>System</Channel> 
  <Computer>PC_NAME</Computer> 
  <Security UserID="ID" /> 
</System>
<EventData>
  <Data Name="Status">3221225524</Data> 
  <Data Name="PortNameLen">36</Data> 
  <Data Name="PortName">ID</Data> 
  <Data Name="PortFNameLen">1</Data> 
  <Data Name="PortFName" /> 
  <Data Name="SwitchNameLen">36</Data> 
  <Data Name="SwitchName">ID</Data> 
  <Data Name="SwitchFNameLen">1</Data> 
  <Data Name="SwitchFName" /> 
  <Data Name="UniqueEvent">9</Data> 
</EventData>
</Event>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've already fixed the problem.
After I ran the command "sfc /scannow" in the cmd, the problem disappeared.

See [my thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/79ceb8b5-a52e-4a84-8dcd-80209f9b7e1a/why-does-hypervvmswitch-produce-an-error-log-of-event-id-15?forum=win10itprovirt) in the Microsoft forum.